# Performance related to deleting objects in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a dictionary where I am constantly adding and removing keys which are pointing to class objects. In turn these class objects are being constantly created and destroyed. In my actual system code I was initially just adding objects without cleaning them up (legacy code), and when I started deleting them I started seeing more sluggishness than I expected so I was wondering:

1. Does performance of deleting an object depend on the **size** of the **object**?
2. Does performance of deleting an object **in a dictionary** depend on the **size** of the **object**?
3. Does performance of deleting an object **in a dictionary** depend on the **size** of the **dictionary**?
4. Is there a better strategy for storing volatile objects? (on the order of 10000 max objects)

Below I have just some basic code I made to try and test, but the time of deleting was in-determinant. One interpreter (PyCharm) would say both deletions take 0 seconds, and my VM alternates saying one will take 0 seconds and the other a microsecond, then the next iteration will switch. I wasn't sure how "large" I would need to make things or if this was really the right approach either.

```
import time

def foo():
    a = dict()
    a[0] = 1
    a[1] = bar()
    return a

class bar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = dict()

o = foo()

time0 = time.time()
del o[0]
time1 = time.time()
del o[1]
time2 = time.time()

print(time1-time0)
print(time2-time1)
```

Comment: The performance of deleting from a dictionary does not depend at all on the object being deleted. Fundamentally, the dictionary contains references to the object. The performance *does* depend on the size of the dictionary.

Comment: You're deleting one dict key. That happens far too fast to reasonably time.

Comment: Also, you should really be using the `timeit` module to do these sorts of performance tests. In any event, what exactly is the nature of your data? Why is it in a `dict` to begin with? Could you just use a `list` and `.append` and `.pop` from the end? This will make adding/removing very fast. The problem with `dict`s is that resizing can be much more sluggish than for a list. What is the nature of your keys, and how are you using them>

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'll look into `timeit`, I hadn't heard of it before. I'm using a `dict` because the object which is being deleted is not necessarily the first or last object, and is more random access (so I can't use `.pop`). I figured if it was random access then storing in a dict would be faster than in a list.

Comment: @nanotek huh? `dict`s give *very fast* access to values from a key. Of course, it isn't faster than *indexing into a list*. But it gives you that same runtime complexity, plus a lot more flexibility on keys. Deleting an arbitrary element from a `dict` has worst-case linear, although on average it is constant. However, the constant factors of deleting and resizing/re-hashing can be quite stark, and may be causing the sluggishness you see. Can you elaborate on your particulars?

Comment: If you are creating (allocating) lots of objects, and removing (deallocating) them, any fluctuations or perceived performance issues are likely caused by memory fragmentation. Dicts themselves are *extremely* fast in python.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga sorry, when I was referring to "random access" I meant that the deletions were random stored objects, not first or last object so I don't think putting them in a list and using `pop` would work. Given that the deletions are more random I figured that adding and deleting from a dictionary would be faster than adding and deleting random elements in a list. I can't really get into the particulars because its system level code I'm working with and gets just gets really complex really fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some tests for both questions :

1. Does performance of deleting an object depends on the size of the object?
2. Does performance of deleting an object in a dictionary depend on the size of the object?

The first question will be difficult to answer as is. Deleting 1 item is so fast that we cannot "benchmark" it easily. Nevertheless, the second questions can also reply to the first one as the difference remains also only on the size of the value.
For this, I used the following script.

```
import random
import string
import time

def generate_string(l):
    return "".join([ random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(l)])

group_short = {}
group_long = {}

for i in range(50000):
    group_short[i] = generate_string(5)
    group_long[i] = generate_string(500)

t_short = time.time()
for i in range(0, 50000, 3):
    del group_short[i]
print(time.time()-t_short)

t_long = time.time()
for j in range(0, 50000, 3):
    del group_long[j]
print(time.time()-t_long)
```

Unfortunately, it takes more time to generate the dictionnaray than delete some items so I can't test it with a very big sample. The "estimated" result is around 25% faster with smaller objects (which is a bit strange because objects are stored as reference and not as value):

1. 0.00200s with short objects
2. 0.00250s with bigger objects

   ---
3. Does performance of deleting an object in a dictionary depend on the size of the dictionary?

For this one, I generated the same size of the string but group_short contains 5000 objects and group_long contains 150000 objects. I deleted the same amount of items and this is the result :

1. 0.00047s for the short dict
2. 0.00150s for the long dict

Based on this we can assume that the length of the dictionnary impacts the time to delete items

---

4. Is there a better strategy for storing volatile objects? (on the order of 10000 max objects)

For this I don't have all the knowledge of all datatypes existing. Nevertheless, this structure is really optimized to access as fast as possible values based on a known key (complexity of O(1)). If your key is an integer based on a range, maybe a numpy array is faster update/access values afterward. This is only depending on the object you want to store (int, float, bool, class, string, etc..). Some types won't be accessible in Numpy.

---

I hope it helps,

Coni